# Can placeholders be used only for Database Events in Firebase and not queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Take a look at the following JSON structure:

```
"Fund_Project_Request" : {
    "-LEEy7uxXEeI4AJuePoB" : {
      "4ZpTt0rHvjYfKAnCukIlhGpH6kz2" : {
        "afds1234" : 2,
        "asdf12" : 2
      },
      "iRfNzDSjFiOADqn3KsG8nNuZEfp2" : {
        "afds1234" : 1
      }
    }
  },
```

Here, if I want to get the values 'afds1234' or 'asdf12' which I'm going to call as 'reward_ids' in an onWrite function, all I have to do is:

```
exports.manipulateRewards = functions.database.ref('/Fund_Project_Request/{ArtcallID}/{UserID}/{rewardID}').onWrite((change, context) => {

 const reward_id = context.params.rewardID;

});
```

Let's say I want to obtain these reward_ids strings without using the onWrite function. Would I be able to do so with a singleValueEventListener or any other method of querying?

Comment: You don't have to query for it.  The value of the location in the database that was changed is available in the `change` object passed to the `onWrite` callback handler function\.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My question is what if I don't want to use the onWrite function and want to get those values by using a listener?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you don't want to use Cloud Functions, why are you showing its code?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I've edited my question now. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what your goal is here.  Are you trying to get your function to do something?

Comment: No, I'm not. I just want to know if there's another method apart from using the onWrite function to obtain these reward_id strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing code to query Realtime Database, there are no wildcards.  You must know the exact path of the data you're interested in.

Cloud Functions triggers aren't really anything like normal listeners.  They are essentially filtering *all* writes that flow through the system, and triggering only on the writes that match the given path.